# Set different admin index pages for each users

Tags: django, django-admin

I am customizing the django admin. I want to set a different index page for staff users and keep the original for superusers.

What I have done is to add a view that looks like this:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin/new_admin/")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin/new_admin/orders/")
```

But there is an extra problem:

1. There is a loop with the url "/admin/new_admin/"

I don't know if this is the best way to do it.

This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/$', 'new_admin.views.home'),
    (r'^admin/',  include(admin.site.urls)), # admin site
)
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/multiple_admin_sites.html

Comment: Post your urls.py to understand how loop is formed. Also any other code associated with it.

Comment: I didn't try that, but is it for handle multiple admin sites, right? I don't know if it is the same, because I am using only the default admin. I just want to customize a view for type of user